# How to design an app with security in mind?

Tags: security

Over the net I encountered following phrase:

> Software security isn't a layer on
>   top of your application, it is
>   incorporated in your application from the very beginning.

But how do you design a system with security in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the first thing, and starting point of all security considerations, you need to define a [threat model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model): what are the things that you want to happen, what are the things you want to prevent from happening, what are the things that you don't care if they happen?

Then, for each threat, explain how your system prevents that threat. What makes the expertise of security experts is primarily an intuition of what threats occur typically in systems. You learn that by reading literature - it's often the same threats that challenge many systems.

Answer (score 1):

Security is made up of a lot of different areas and is frankly a massive field.  I could give you some bullet points but you really need to research.  For example:

- Store passwords as (salted) hashes
- Cleanse all input from any external systems
- Keep and check comprehensive logs
- Perform software updates

But like I say - this is a massive area that changes constantly.  Your best bet would be to grab a book on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Threat models are nonsense, anything that a security "expert" suggests is probably garbage. Code isn't secure if it's only secure under specific circumstances. Proper encapsulation is congruent to security, which is what E proves.

Check out the [E](http://erights.org/) language, which has orthogonal security (object capability model) made easy. It's a good proof of concept, there are other languages like this too, such as Joe-E, which is the same paradigm for Java, Emily for Ocaml, Oz-E for Oz. Unfortunately, E is dynamically typed, but fortunately it's done in a much smarter way than other dynamically typed languages I've seen. Even if you don't end up using E for anything, it will still teach you how security comes natural with sound design.

This is actually how security should be done; when I think of a computer, I think of a device made to run algorithms and software. Never did I expect a flash game to be able to compromise my entire system and steal all my data. But a few days ago I was running a fully up to date windows 7 install on my lab PC, and it got compromised after browsing the internet with a fully updated Firefox/Flash after a day. This is not how computing should work, you shouldn't have to worry that reading a certain piece of text will make your bank account get stolen. But the unfortunate fact is that every de-facto O/S is fundamentally flawed in this way, and will always be, because they are written in unsafe languages.

Anyways, some fundamental things that will help security:

- no global mutable state, there is no reason for it, ever.
- sort of the above: don't write to random hardcoded paths in the filesystem, it will cause clashes and more bugs, and vulnerabilities. Ideally, you should just get a handle to some persistent storage passed to your program by the OS, which you can read/write to, then it would be impossible to clash, Java's java.util.prefs.Preferences does exactly this
- try to deal with strongly typed data as much as possible. stay away from toy languages that encourage parsing text to do everything and languages who are weakly typed, such as bash, Perl, PHP, JavaScript, tcl, C/C++*, Python**, etc. Every time you are manually escaping HTML, escaping input to a bash command, escaping input to SQL, you are asking for trouble. Speaking of HTML, avoid making your application for the web if possible, as the web was not made to be secure.
- no eval, that's stupid
- encapsulate properly, this is vital in any orthogonal security language, you can't make a function called getSocket() that creates a file in your system and renames ~/home/lol to ~/home/wtf, follow the Law of Demeter.

Basically, just follow good practices (which don't exist much in the real world), and you'll be secure. Sound design = Security = Speed = Usability (but not dumbed down). Encapsulation is key, E forces you to do proper encapsulation.

*C/C++ are forbidden. period. Not even the best mathematicians in the world can write large scale C/C++ programs without major vulnerabilities. The best case I know of was a ~4000K line microkernel which ended up with 250K lines of proof. I've never seen a large video game written in C++ without major vulnerabilities.

**Python is strongly typed, but it is still error prone, because it encourages doing things like monkey patching, inheritance (but there is no way to prevent private member name clashes, which is a problem all the time). Scope is virtual, so when you access any local variable it looks it up in a dict. It has eval/exec. Everyone just pickles things, which leads to arbitrary code execution (ie, you can never use someone else's Python program data because it might have a pickle which will own you when you read from it). It's slow as hell and probably always will be compared to statically typed languages.

Comment: Okay downvoters, I answered how to *actually* design an app with security in mind, not how to make something that works on top of legacy nonsense, or something that can be created by incompetent hackers.

Comment: You are right. Our OS, and languages we run our software are flawed. When this is fixed and don't write applications connected to the internet, we will be safe. However, this doesn't help anyone. You are pointing to an experimental language that no professional developer can use today in production. Besides, we have to build our system today on the platforms that are available today. And advising developers to "avoid making applications for the web" is just silly.

Comment: @Steven: There's nothing wrong or insecure about programs that use the the Internet, Internet != web. It's not hard at all to make something securely run and interact with untrusted peers, why would you let the peer do anything you don't want them to do? Sounds like a joke, something like what would happen in C or PHP, but not any serious language.

Answer (score 0):

There are software development processes, such as the Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) by Microsoft that you can use side-by-side with your normal development methodology during the development. The quote is very correct, you can't add security to an application after your done, or when you do so, it will be much more expensive than doing this from the very beginning. A security process can help you figuring out where the risks are (risk management) and protecting that parts of the application that are contain the most sensitive information.

It's hard however, for a moral developer (like myself) to develop secure software. If security is valuable enough for your boss or your customer: hire a security engineer. He should be able to help you with the whole process.

Comment: Security isn't hard, that's a myth. It is hard to have security with existing systems that are fundamentally insecure, though (*cough* *cough* that 50 million line of C/C++ OS).

Comment: Yep, but that is the situation we have to deal with as developers in our normal live. And that what makes security hard. I've seen developers did a very good job in protecting that applications by having multiple layers of defense, but one single mistake and their complete application became open to attack. That's why it's hard and that's why you need to use a security process and someone who understands that process.